# Connection reset error

Tags: error

Every time I try to "add new event" I keep getting message ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from my google chrome and the webpage doesnt open.. What could be to cause? 
I''m using wampserver x64, civicrm-5.3.1-wordpress, wordpress-4.9.6-pl_PL.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show any relevant log entries in your web server and/or CiviCRM log?

Comment: That sounds like a timeout.